# Adding items to a div with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a div element in which I want to show one item on a click of a button. But every time a user clicks a button, I want him to be able to add another item, and another, etc. Making it a list.

How do I accomplish this with React?

I know I have to separate an item, right?

```
const Item = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
)
```

And then? I'm assuming it's not the same as simply showing/hiding a div with ternary operators? Because the button needs to add +1 every time someone clicks it. Or am I wrong?

Can someone please point me in the right direction because I'm not sure how to search this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put store your item data to state, then use map on that state e.g.

If you use hooks for state.

```
{items && items.map(item => <Item someProp={item.someValue} />)}
```

If you have a class based component.

```
{this.state.items && this.state.items.map(item => <Item someProp={item.someValue} />)}
```

Note the && is there so react doesn't try to map over a empty state and only maps if the value is truthy aka in this case the state has something in it, if you would try to map over a empty state it would crash react.